# Try/Catch Loop with return value

Tags: java, loops, try-catch

I'm new to programming, so I just need some help. I kinda figured out some things on my own, but now now I am lost I would say. Keep in mind that I'm not a native speaker, so sorry for my mistakes :)
I'm learning Java in my University, but we have to do exercises on our own.
The program is about typing in an interval like 1 and 20, the program squares it and I need to find the right answer to it. I have 3 tries to get the correct answer. After the third try I get to ask if I want to try another Number or end the program

The actual problem that I got is, the "try and catch loop", which needs to test that I enter a positive Number.

```
public static int prüfung(int ZahlPrüfen) {
    while (true) {
        try {

            ZahlPrüfen = IntervallScanner.nextInt();
            if (IntervallScanner.hasNextInt() && ZahlPrüfen > 0) {
                return ZahlPrüfen;

            } else if (ZahlPrüfen <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Bitte Geben Sie eine Positive Zahl ein");
                IntervallScanner.next();

            }

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Bitte Geben Sie eine Zahl und keinen Buchstaben ein");
            IntervallScanner.next();

        }
    }
```

The Problem kinda is that, if I enter a positive Number (so everything right), I have to type it in twice! Same when I type in a negative Number, I need to type it twice. I get an "error" when i type in a string, so that works kinda fine i guess. it shows like this:

> Bitte geben Sie die kleinste positive Zahl des Intervalls ein: -2
>
> -3
>
> Bitte Geben Sie eine Positive Zahl ein
>
> -4
>
> -5
>
> Bitte Geben Sie eine Positive Zahl ein
>
> -6
>
> -7
>
> Bitte Geben Sie eine Positive Zahl ein
>
> 2
>
> 2
>
> Bitte geben Sie die Größte Zahl des Intervalls ein: 3
>
> Wie lautet die Wurzel aus 4?

And The code takes the first time when i type in the correct numbers like in this case 2 and 2, and uses them to make the random number, and not 2 and 3.

I hope you can understand what I mean this far. It would be real great if someone of you guys can help me, I'm stuck like for 5 hours and cant figure it out. My brain just stops working :D

Here is the complete code:

```
public static int zufallszahl = 0;
public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public static Scanner eingabe = new Scanner(System.in);
public static Scanner IntervallScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
public static int AnzahlVersuche = 0;
public static int k = 0;
public static int kleineZahl;
public static int großeZahl;
public static int ZahlPrüfen;
public static int ZahlPrüfung;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("Bitte geben Sie die kleinste positive Zahl des Intervalls ein: ");

    kleineZahl = prüfung(ZahlPrüfen);

    System.out.print("Bitte geben Sie die Größte Zahl des Intervalls ein: ");

    großeZahl = prüfung(ZahlPrüfen);

    do {
        ermittleZufallszahl(großeZahl, kleineZahl);

        int quadrad = (int) Math.pow(zufallszahl, 2);
        System.out.println("Wie lautet die Wurzel aus " + quadrad + "?");

        erneuterVersuch();

    } while (k == 1);
}

public static void ermittleZufallszahl(int max, int min) {
    zufallszahl = (int) ((Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);

}

public static int erneuterVersuch() {
    AnzahlVersuche = 0;
    while (AnzahlVersuche <= 2) {
        int input = sc.nextInt();
        if (input == zufallszahl) {
            System.out.println("Das ist richtig,toll!");
            System.out.println("Wollen Sie eine andere Zahl probieren? Wenn Ja geben Sie (j) ein, wenn Nein geben Sie (n) ein.");
            String eingabe1 = eingabe.nextLine();
            switch (eingabe1) {
                case "j":
                case "J":

                    k = 1;

                    return k;

                case "n":
                case "N":
                    System.out.println("Programm wird jetzt beendet");
                    k = 2;
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Das ist falsch, schade!");

            ++AnzahlVersuche;
            if (AnzahlVersuche == 3) {
                System.out.println("Sie haben es mit 3 Versuchen leider nicht geschafft! Die richtige Antwort wäre " + zufallszahl + " gewesen.");
                System.out.println("Wollen Sie eine andere Zahl probieren? Wenn Ja geben Sie (j) ein, wenn Nein geben Sie (n) ein.");

                String eingabe1 = eingabe.nextLine();
                switch (eingabe1) {
                    case "j":
                    case "J":

                        k = 1;

                        break;
                    case "n":
                    case "N":
                        System.out.println("Programm wird jetzt beendet");
                        k = 2;
                        System.exit(0);
                }

            }

        }
    }
    return k;
}

public static int prüfung(int ZahlPrüfen) {

    while (true) {
        try {

            ZahlPrüfen = IntervallScanner.nextInt();
            if (IntervallScanner.hasNextInt() && ZahlPrüfen > 0) {
                return ZahlPrüfen;

            } else if (ZahlPrüfen <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Bitte Geben Sie eine Positive Zahl ein");
                IntervallScanner.next();

            }

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Bitte Geben Sie eine Zahl und keinen Buchstaben ein");
            IntervallScanner.next();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do not use Umlaute in method or variable names. Just a sidenote.

Comment: Okay i will change it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wie gehts :)

Ich verstehe das nicht :/

```
 public static int prüfung(int ZahlPrüfen) {
  while (true) {
    try {

        int ZahlPrüfen = IntervallScanner.nextInt();
        if (IntervallScanner.hasNextInt() && ZahlPrüfen > 0) {
            return ZahlPrüfen;

        } else if (ZahlPrüfen <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Bitte Geben Sie eine Positive Zahl ein");
            IntervallScanner.next();
        }

    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Bitte Geben Sie eine Zahl und keinen Buchstaben ein");
        IntervallScanner.next();

    }
}
```

You're passing in `ZahlPrufen`, but you replace it with `IntervallScanner.nextInt();`. So the value passed in was never used.

You don't need the method to take in an argument.

The error lies in you checking for hasNextInt() in your if condition, which expects another input from the user. You just need to check the validity of the number that was just input.

```
public static int prüfung() {
while (true) {

    try {
    int ZahlPrüfen = IntervallScanner.nextInt();
    if (ZahlPrüfen > 0) {
        return ZahlPrüfen;

    } else {
        System.out.println("Bitte Geben Sie eine Positive Zahl ein");
    }

  } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
      System.out.println("Bitte Geben Sie eine Zahl und keinen Buchstaben ein");
        IntervallScanner.next();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Tom This is very fascinating. I wasn't encountering the infinite loop because my ```Scanner IntervallScanner = new Scanner(System.in);``` was inside the while loop, and so the Scanner was getting recreated with each iteration.

Comment: @Tom I fixed my answer, and it resolves the original issue of expecting double input. Really all that was wrong was the ```IntervallScanner.hasNextInt()``` check in the if condition.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just edited it and it works kinda. But if I enter a negative number, it wants me to enter two negative or 2 positive numbers. It works normal when I enter positive numbers right away or get the error with entering some letters. It looks like this: Bitte Geben Sie eine Positive Zahl ein
-6
-7
Bitte Geben Sie eine Positive Zahl ein
3
5
Bitte geben Sie die Größte Zahl des Intervalls ein: 10

Comment: @bubele1 Consider accepting the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: I just editied my comment :D, i thought I can press enter to make more space but it just sent it right away.

Comment: Oh wait, i think I "fixed" it by deleting the IntervallScanner.next(); from the else part. Could this be right?

Comment: Yes, the `IntervallScanner.next()` statement is wrong in the `else` branch. You just need it in the `catch` block.

Comment: Dang it I fixed it. But good job figuring it out on your own!